# Getting the error: 'A valid React element (or null) must be returned' error with one of the component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, render

Below is my code

```
 render() {
  const mainSection = (
    <MainSection
        title={ __( 'main.section.title' ) }
        onClose={ this.handleOnClose }
    />
  );

  const secondarySection = (

      {
        this.state.error ? (
        <Message
            onClose={ this.handleMessageClose }
            style={ styles.message }
        >
          { this.state.error }
        </Message>
        ) : null
      }

      <div>
        <SecondaryForm
            data={ {
              username: this.state.username,
              } }
              onChangeUsername={ this.handleUsernameChange }
              onSaveUsername={ this.handleSaveUserName }
        />
      </div>
  );
  return (
         this.state.show.section === true ? { secondarySection } : { mainSection }
    );
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have
>   returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Please Help me in this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do that guys said and just remove {} from `this.state.show.section === true ? { secondarySection } : { mainSection }` like `this.state.show.section === true ?  secondarySection  :  mainSection`

Answer (score 0):

Your secondarySection is a couple of elements. If your render method must return `<X1/>` and `<X2/>`, wrap them like  `<div><X1/><X2/></div>` so that its all inside a single element. React assumes each component would be an element or null, so it rejects anything else.

```
  const secondarySection = (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.error ? (
        <Message
            onClose={ this.handleMessageClose }
            style={ styles.message }
        >
          { this.state.error }
        </Message>
        ) : null
      }

      <div>
        <SecondaryForm
            data={ {
              username: this.state.username,
              } }
              onChangeUsername={ this.handleUsernameChange }
              onSaveUsername={ this.handleSaveUserName }
        />
      </div>
  </div>
  );
```

Comment: It should be `this.state.show.section === true ?  secondarySection  :  mainSection `. Thanks Andrew, for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Components should return only one element. You need to wrap your return in a single element/div.

You code should looks like:

```
render() {
  const mainSection = (
    <MainSection
        title={ __( 'main.section.title' ) }
        onClose={ this.handleOnClose }
    />
  );

  const secondarySection = (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.error ? (
          <Message
              onClose={ this.handleMessageClose }
              style={ styles.message }
          >
            { this.state.error }
          </Message>
          ) : null
        }

        <SecondaryForm
            data={ {
              username: this.state.username,
              } }
              onChangeUsername={ this.handleUsernameChange }
              onSaveUsername={ this.handleSaveUserName }
        />
      </div>
  );
  return (
         this.state.show.section === true ? { secondarySection } : { mainSection }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should also add a wrapper 
return(
        <div>
          {this.state.show.section === true ? secondarySection :  mainSection } 
        </div>
    );

Answer (score 0):

**Changes**:

*Use `{}` to use a javascript code inside html element, once you use `{}` then no to put another `{}` inside that like you used in ternary operator.

*`JSX` can't return more than one element so always try to wrap all the code in a `<div>` or by any other wrapper element.

Try this:

```
render() {
  const mainSection = (
    <MainSection
        title={ __( 'main.section.title' ) }
        onClose={ this.handleOnClose }
    />
  );

  const secondarySection = this.state.error ? 
        <div>
           <Message
              onClose={ this.handleMessageClose }
              style={ styles.message }
           >
              { this.state.error }
           </Message>
           <SecondaryForm
              data={
                {username: this.state.username,}
              }
              onChangeUsername={ this.handleUsernameChange }
              onSaveUsername={ this.handleSaveUserName }
           />
        </div>
        : null;   

  return(
        <div>
          {this.state.show.section === true ? secondarySection :  mainSection } 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: still facing any issue ?